passed a socket to a method which is wrapped with shared ptr but beast tcp stream socket generate error stating that the socket is deleted
void connections::start_acceptor(){

    auto socket=std::make_shared<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>(ioc);

    con_acceptor.async_accept(*socket,[this,socket](const boost::system::error_code ec){

        if(!ec){

            this->status=true;

            if(socket->is_open()){

                cout<<"client connection Acknoledged with ip - "<<socket->remote_endpoint()<<endl;

                boost::asio::spawn(con_acceptor.get_executor(), [this,socket](boost::asio::yield_context yield) {

                    r_w_handler(socket, yield);

                });

            };

            this->start_acceptor();

        } else{

            cout<<"Error Accepting - "<<ec.message()<<endl;

            this->status=false;

            this->start_listener();

        }

    });
};


void connections::r_w_handler(std::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, boost::asio::yield_context yield) {

        boost::beast::tcp_stream stream_socket(*socket);

        try {

            char data[128];

            for (;;) {

                // std::size_t length = socket->async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data), yield);

                // boost::asio::async_write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer(data, length), yield);

            }

        } catch (const std::exception& e) {

            std::cerr <<" Error with session " << e.what() << std::endl;

        }

};

after compiling this was the error generated
error: use of deleted function
boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol, Executor>::basic_stream_socket(const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<Protocol, Executor>&) [with Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]


Please show the full text of the compiler output though it's likely where you're copying the socket into the steam it's complaining about boost::beast::tcp_stream stream_socket(*socket);

The message doesn't say the socket is deleted.
It means you're trying to copy a non-copyable type.
The copy happens here:
beast::tcp_stream stream_socket(*socket);

Specifically, due to *socket. If you make it
beast::tcp_stream stream_socket(std::move(*socket));

The particular error goes away.
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace asio  = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
using tcp       = asio::ip::tcp;
#include <iostream>

struct connections {
    connections(asio::io_context& ioc, tcp::endpoint endpoint);

    void start_listener();
    void acceptLoop();
    void r_w_handler(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket, asio::yield_context yield);

    asio::io_context& ioc_;
    tcp::acceptor     acc_;
    bool              status_;
};

void connections::acceptLoop() {
    auto socket = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(ioc_);
    acc_.async_accept(*socket, [this, socket](boost::system::error_code const ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            status_ = true;

            if (socket->is_open()) {

                std::cout << "client connection Acknoledged with ip - " << socket->remote_endpoint()
                          << std::endl;

                asio::spawn(
                    acc_.get_executor(),
                    [this, socket](asio::yield_context yield) { r_w_handler(socket, yield); },
                    asio::detached);
            };

            acceptLoop();
        } else {

            std::cout << "Error Accepting - " << ec.message() << std::endl;

            status_ = false;
            start_listener();
        }
    });
};

void connections::r_w_handler(std::shared_ptr<asio::ip::tcp::socket> socket, asio::yield_context yield) {
    beast::tcp_stream stream_socket(std::move(*socket));
    try {
        char data[128];
        for (;;) {

            std::size_t length = socket->async_read_some(asio::buffer(data), yield);

            asio::async_write(*socket, asio::buffer(data, length), yield);
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << " Error with session " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
};

connections::connections(asio::io_context& ioc, tcp::endpoint endpoint)
    : ioc_(ioc)
    , acc_(ioc, endpoint)
    , status_(false) {
}

void connections::start_listener() {
    acc_.listen();
    acceptLoop();
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    tcp::endpoint   endpoint(tcp::v4(), 8989);
    connections     conn(ioc, endpoint);
    conn.start_listener();
    ioc.run();
}

Note that it no longer makes much sense to make_shared the socket in the first place: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6eaa017b07f1638e

Added a variation without any shared pointers

build was successful. thank you
